# Not a duplicate - Is there any 3g data package that works across Europe?

Tags: discussion

The question [Is there any 3g data package that works across Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5902/is-there-any-3g-data-package-that-works-across-europe) was closed as a duplicate of [Choices for prepaid GSM data with laptop tethering in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/choices-for-prepaid-gsm-data-with-laptop-tethering-in-europe). I originally agreed with this, but there are a number of differences between the questions.

1. Many carriers are openly hostile to tethering and threaten to charge full rates (several dollars per MB) if you are caught or to cut off your service.
2. Tethering restricts the question to plans with large data caps

I suppose an argument could be made that it should be closed as a ["shopping" question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/651/do-we-really-want-all-these-best-phone-for-country-x-questions), but in this case it would apply to both questions.

Answer (score -1):

Two parallel questions would be counter-productive. I would suggest editing the previous question to ask for both tethered and non-tethered data plans. Then perhaps I / any kind soul can call attention to it again with a bounty.

Comment: Changing the scope of the question is rarely done on StackExchange except to move a question on topic