# Improve "price shopping" off-topic text

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

We have an off-topic close reason for **price shopping**:

> Questions on **price-shopping for specific goods or services** are off-topic as prices and availability change frequently in many locations. See: [What is a shopping question?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-is-a-shopping-question)

Yet we seem to allow price-shopping questions (while avoiding other shopping questions).  A recent example is [this question about finding lodging in Okinawa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25500/444), which as of this writing has **7 up votes, 0 down votes, and 44 views**, which seems to indicate there's a relatively strong consensus that it's a *good question*.

Is it time to adjust the text for our shopping off-topic text to reflect our enforced policy?

Comment: Here's the useful part of my comment from the question: The idea of good vs bad shopping questions originates in the Stack Exchange blog post from a couple of years ago titled ***[Q&A is Hard, Let's go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)*** Reading this will clear up which kinds of shopping questions should not be on the site. Basically subjective recommendation questions, which this is not.

Comment: @hippietrail: I agree with that distinction.  I just think the off-topic text should probably say that. Anyone would be justified in thinking that your question should be off-topic if they only read that text.

Comment: Yes exactly. I just wanted the link and reasoning to be here for other people to be able to check too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at the very least adding a link to [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) would be helpful.

Possibly **instead** of the link to [What is a shopping question?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-is-a-shopping-question) because the Accepted answer there (+10/-1), I believe from a Community Mod at the time, does not to me seem fully to reflect current practice and convention. In particular:

> If your question is more about acquiring x than it is about what you're going to do with x as part of your travels, then it's generally not going to be a good fit for the site.

whereas subsequent to the above we have [Rule 2: Don't judge people's motivations for traveling](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/rule-2-dont-judge-peoples-motivations-for-traveling) and many Open questions (eg [Cost-effective solution to get to work by train in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81638/cost-effective-solution-to-get-to-work-by-train-in-the-uk)) despite:

> If a local might have the same question, then it's not a travel-related question.

Comment: I support the idea of linking to https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ as well. I will ask the other mods and edit ASAP if consensus exists.