# Price-shopping or shopping questions?

Tags: discussion

One of the grounds to close a question as off-topic reads:

> Questions on price-shopping for specific goods or services are off-topic as prices and availability change frequently in many locations. See: What is a shopping question?

How does it apply to [How to Buy Schladerer Kirschwasser in Frankfurt, Germany?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50896/how-to-buy-schladerer-kirschwasser-in-frankfurt-germany) (three votes to close as of writing this)?

Comment: Is this intended to be a poll of sorts?

Comment: @CMaster A way to establish consensus, yes, like most questions on meta.

Answer (score 7):

The justification mentions price *and availability*. The question might not strictly speaking be a *price*-shopping question but availability can also change quickly and the question is unlikely to have long-term value to anyone.

We might want to amend the text to broaden the scope of the rule a bit.

Answer (score 7):

Quite clearly, the rule does not apply. It's not a *price*-shopping question and can be interesting to other travellers seeking this local delicacy as information of this sort typically remains valid for many years.

Rule-creep is not a good thing and if the point was to forbid all shopping-related questions, that particular justification would not be formulated in that way. Furthermore, [older discussions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-is-a-shopping-question) confirm that discouraging questions about the *best price* for something that's widely available (as opposed to tracking down hard-to-find products) was really the concern here.

We might want to remove the word “availability” to make that even clearer.

Comment: @pnuts The idea is that it would make it crystal clear that the issue is asking about price ("Where can I buy XXX for the lowest price?”) but that other shopping-related questions are OK.

Comment: @pnuts That would be my interpretation as well but seeing the close votes and the response to this meta question, I am not sure that's really clear to most people.

Comment: @pnuts Probably, yes. I was hoping for a clearer result one way or the other but that ship has sailed.