# Are questions looking for a business that sells a specific item on- or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

What is our stance on questions looking for a business that sells a specific item? On-topic or off-topic as not related to travel?

I see that there exist 200+ questions such questions in [shopping](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping), e.g.:

1. [Where can I find good quality chocolates in Bahamas (Bahamas airport)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/151529/1810)
2. [Is there somewhere to buy used Latvian books in Riga?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/150835/1810)
3. [Does Estonia have discount supermarket chains like Aldi and Lidl?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/149973/1810)
4. [Cheap second-hand bookstores in Vilnius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/143665/1810)

but sometimes they are closed e.g. [Where can I get custom-fitted earplugs in Bangkok? [closed]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158361/1810), so I'm confused regarding the scope of this website.

Comment: Gentle reminder to Be Kind in our comments

Answer (score 4):

As one who thought your question on ear-plugs was off-topic, as a shopping and not travel question, I would like to offer my opinion on the other [shopping](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping) questions.

Yes, I believe most of the other shopping questions are **also off-topic** and should be closed.  But not all of them.  And yes, I know in my comment on your Q&A I said that most were on-topic, but after you responded with some links I took a deeper look and now have changed my view.

I think allowing them has opened the door to questions like (using the example I commented on your question)

> I'm currently visiting Tijuana and need tyres for my car before I drive to San Francisco.  Where in Tijuana can I buy
> good-quality, American known brand, tyres and have them fitted to my vehicle?

Now clearly (at least to me) this is not a *Travel* question, it's a shopping question.  But I use my vehicle for travel, and I'm about to take a long trip in said vehicle, so maybe it's on-topic.  **No, I don't believe so**

And I would argue that most of the [shopping](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping) questions are similar to this.  User has traveled somewhere and now wants to buy something.  The buying has nothing to do with the traveling, so it's a shopping question not a travel question.

That all said, I believe that there are some that *are* on-topic.  From the four linked in the question, I would vote for  [Does Estonia have discount supermarket chains like Aldi and Lidl?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/149973/1810) to remain open.  This, to me, is a question asked by a traveler about what to expect when they arrive, and makes it more on-topic than most of the answers.

I think we should expand the existing Close reason to cover off-topic shopping questions, not just price shopping.  Something like

> Questions on shopping for specific goods or services are off-topic as
> prices and availability change frequently in many locations. Questions
> on where to buy items or who to buy from are off-topic as these are
> not travel related.

(OK so that needs work...)

**See also [What is a shopping question?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-is-a-shopping-question) (which is, in fact, linked from our existing Price Shopping close reason)**

Now, could my Tijuana tyres example, and your ear-plugs question be adjusted to be more on-topic?  Yes, probably...

> I'm currently visiting Tijuana and need tyres for my car before I
> drive to San Francisco. I'm sure there are tyre shops in the city, I
> just don't know what I'm looking for.  What do I need to look for to
> find "tyre shop" in Tijuana?

which could potentially be answered with something like:

> A tyre shop in Tijuana is known as a **Llantera** - there are many
> around, just look for signs with the word Llantera and you'll be in
> the right place.  Or ask a local for directions to the nearest
> llantera (the ll makes a kind of y sound)

Answer (score 0):

I'd liken questions like 'Is there a bookshop in Vilnius?' to 'Is there a zoo in Vilnius?' (or swimming pool, gay bar, whatever). They seem to me to be reasonable questions for someone intending to visit a city.

When the focus switches to a specific product then it's clear that it's a shopping question. If the item(s) are clearly travel-related (air-sick pills, for example) then as a community we might be more tolerant, although the answer is likely to be fairly obvious.

For highly specialised items not obviously related to travel - there's no question. They're off-topic. A question doesn't become a travel question just because one is not at home when one thinks to ask it.

Comment: I don't see how a book is more closely related to travel than some earplug. I'd argue the contrary: you don't need a book to travel, but if you wish to sleep in a train or airplane, earplugs help.